# Adding shadow layer with rounded corners on custom UIButton subclass

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

#### I'm trying to apply a shadow and rounded corners on custom UIButton subclass to use in on the storyboard

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class customButton: UIButton {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setup()
    setGradientBackground()
    setShadowLayer()
}

private func setup() {
    clipsToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = 8
}

private func setGradientBackground() {

    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [
        UIColor(red: 0.18, green: 0.5, blue: 0.93, alpha: 1).cgColor,
        UIColor(red: 0.18, green: 0.61, blue: 0.86, alpha: 1).cgColor
    ]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0,1]
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.25, y: 0.5)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
}

private func setShadowLayer(){
    
    let subLayer = CALayer()
    subLayer.frame = bounds
    subLayer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 8).cgPath
    subLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    subLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
    subLayer.shadowRadius = 12
    subLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    
    layer.insertSublayer(subLayer, at: 0)
}

}
```

When I'm setting the `clipsToBounds` to `true` it remove the shadow, so I decided to add a new sublayer `func setShadowLayer()` and nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try also setting the `.cornerRadius` on the gradient layer:

```
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.75, y: 0.5)

    // add this line        
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 8

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

My result:

[image]